# incompatible types: numeric and bigint. In PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

While migrating to postgresql, I'm facing below issue

Key columns `veh_reg_authority` and `id` are of incompatible types: `numeric` and `bigint`.
Below are mappings:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "VEH_REG_AUTHORITY", columnDefinition ="Numeric(12,0)")
private VehicleRegistrationAuthority vehicleRegistrationAuthority;
```

`VehicleRegistrationAuthority` has `id` of type `Long` so which in converted to `BIGINT` as per PostgreSQL.

So one simple solution is to change columnDefinition ="Numeric(12,0)" accordingly, but we can't do that as it works well with oracle and mysql, and it's been used heavily in out code so not possible to change.

Below are types in Oracle, Mysql, and PostgreSQL:

```
column                          java type             Oracle     Mysql   PostgreSQL
id                               Long                 NUMBER     BIGINT  BIGINT
veh_reg_authority VehicleRegistrationAuthority        NUMBER   decimal(12,0) NUMERIC
```

While creating foreign key hibernate gives below issue.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: foreign key constraint "fk7gyqskn6x2l2910xhhtjgvh0j" cannot be implemented
Detail: Key columns "veh_reg_authority" and "id" are of incompatible types: numeric and bigint.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same data type for both columns if you want to define a foreign key constraint.

If your application works fine in Oracle using the data type `NUMBER` for both columns, why should it not work in PostgreSQL if you use `numeric` for both? These data types are comparable.

Comment: Actually when you use Long (java type) Hibernate maps it to java.sql.Types.BIGINT(JDBC type ) which if mapped to BIGINT in postgresql. And for some specific precision based number's we have to use Numeric. Numeric and BIGINT are compatible in MYSQL and Oracle uses NUMBER for both BIGINT, and NUMERIC so no problems are there on mysql and oracle.

Comment: You should use the same Java type for both columns, everything else is wrong. Then the problem goes away.